# A few coding convention/standard practice questions

Tags: c++

I have this function that takes a string from main. The string contains all of the valid characters that a user can input from some menu options. Function will put character input into a variable and be compared to each character of the string. Compare input variable to the string characters until valid input is entered.

My question is, what is the best way to implement this loop? I don't like using `while (true)` with a `return` in the middle because it looks like an infinite loop with an exception in the middle, which makes it slightly harder to read, but I'm not sure how else I can do what I want it to do. What's the best practice for achieving my goal? Thanks.

```
char getValidKey(string validKeys)
{
    char letter;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Operation ? ";
        cin >> letter;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < validKeys.length(); i++) {

            if (letter == validKeys[i])
                return letter;
        }

        cout << "Error. Invalid input.\n";
    }
}
```

Also, I have a switch statement with multiple returns. Is it more common/preferred to assign calculations to a variable and have one return at the end or is this way generally okay?

```
string opStr;

switch (myOperation) {
    case 1:
        opStr = "RIGHT";
        break;
    case 2:
        opStr = "LEFT";
        break;
    case 3:
        opStr = "CENTER_ONLY";
        break;
    case 4:
        opStr = "CENTER_MISSING";
        break;
    default:
        opStr = "Error. Invalid input.";
        break;
}

return opStr;
```

OR

```
switch (myOperation) {
    case 1:
        return "RIGHT";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "LEFT";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "CENTER_ONLY";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "CENTER_MISSING";
        break;
    default:
        return "Error. Invalid input.";
        break;
}
```

Comment: In the second example of `switch`, you don't need even need `break`, since it won't, ever, be reached - making it shorter than the first example.

Comment: `std::find` can replace your `for` loop. It only looks more complicated the first time, eventually you will appreciate giving your loops meaningful names.

Comment: 1. You can go with this, but I'd prefer something like `bool running = true; while(running){ ... if(some_condition){running = false;}}`, but that is personal taste. 2. Both switch assignments look fine. Do what you prefer. In the second case you might even want to remove the breaks. In most situations, you will probably make the default case to break and then return the error after the switch. In conclusion: In those cases, all your options are just fine, just decide for one style and keep with it.

Comment: The "single entry, single exit" idea is not widely used in c++.  Having each case return its specific value is much easier to read. But I'd worry that the error condition is just some fixed string, otherwise indistinguishable from the other states.

Comment: This is more of a coding style question than a programming error question, and thus a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

For the first case, refactor your code in smaller self-contained functions, and it becomes clear to understand the logic of `getValidKey` even from a `while(true)`:

```
char isKeyValid(char x, const string& validKeys)
{
    return validKeys.find(x) != string::npos;
}

char readCharFromCin()
{
    char letter;

    cout << "Operation ? ";
    cin >> letter;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    return letter;
}

char getValidKey(const string& validKeys)
{
    while (true) 
    {
        const char key = readCharFromCin();
        if(isKeyValid(key, validKeys)) return letter;

        cout << "Error. Invalid input.\n";
    }
}
```

---

For the second case, avoid `break` and simply return from your `switch`. Make the function containing the `switch` only do one thing.

```
string switchOperation(int myOperation)
{
    switch (myOperation) 
    {
        case 1:  return "RIGHT";
        case 2:  return "LEFT";
        case 3:  return "CENTER_ONLY";
        case 4:  return "CENTER_MISSING";
    }

    return "Error. Invalid input.";
}
```

---

Also, try to maximize usage of `const` and pass `string` instances you're only reading by `const&` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: +1, nice refactoring into smaller functions.  I worry about switchOperation's error return being indistinguishable from normal strings.

Comment: @KennyOstrom: definitely a good point. The return type should be a `variant<string, error>` - I feel like this would complicate the answer too much, assuming the OP is a beginner.

Comment: or pair, or throw exception (also tough on beginner), but there's a much easier way.  bool getOperationDescription(int myOperation, std::string &description);  If left as is, then I hope he replaces that error string with something like const std::string INVALID_OPERATION (so the actual text is only ever in one place, in case someone changes it).